# How can I indicate I am not trying to master a technology I am using?

Tags: discussion

In https://stackoverflow.com/q/38381594/3001761, I requested help in what should be a fairly basic AngularJS thing to do. The first comment ran:

> You really ought to start by going through some angular tutorials ... pluralsight has some good ones. Trying to learn a new framework by asking questions on SO is not a good approach

The commenter appears to assume that if I'm asking a question about a particular technology, that means it must be my goal to learn more about that technology, but I am not really interested in learning AngularJS to any high level.

I don't know if this smells of "Give me da codez," but my goal in posting was to solve something that I'd expect a good AngularJS developer could do in five minutes, and I posted my work thus far (since then, I solved the problem myself and posted my results).

Is there (or should there be) a mechanism to annotate posts as *"I'm not trying to master AngularJS? I'm working on a site where I want to use AngularJS for one page."* or otherwise expand metamessages to recognize that the bounds of Stack Overflow are not just *"I want to go all the way to expert status in XYZ"* but *"My goals for XYZ are modest for now"*?

Comment: Did you post the right question? The question was asked by another user and answered by a different user as well? As for the context, I don't think they were trying to talk down to you, just providing areas where you can do suitable research to solve it yourself. Why have someone else do it, when you can learn and use it possibly in the future? I understand you don't want to be a master, but there is no harm in becoming proficient for the next time you might need to use the technology

Comment: Ugh that question's title is _horrible_. Please choose a title that describes the problem you're facing.

Comment: I had to read the question twice to start figuring out what the problem/question is, a clarifying edit would certainly be helpful. (Can't judge whether the commenter was right, or being unfair - I don't know the framework.)

Comment: This is pointless.  Comments are not commands, and random people on the internet cannot make you do things you don't want to do.  ... ... or maybe they can?  I need you to get on paypal and wire me some cash.  Now.  Do it.

Comment: @Mat I've hopefully made the meta title a bit more accurate. But the linked AngularJS question needs work, too...

Comment: I've gone and edited that too. I'm not sure if I understood what you were asking (which is a problem in itself), but it seems to be better.

Answer (score 16):

I don't see any problem with that comment, it's a perfectly sensible suggestion and in line with the guidance from e.g. [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/3001761) They didn't suggest that you *"master AngularJS"*, just that you put some effort into understanding the technology you're using; tutorials generally cover the basics, after all.

To put it another way: if you're not interested in becoming better at using AngularJS, why use it at all? You seem to be asking a couple of questions around it, so evidently you *need* to become better at using it; just asking a question on SO for each incremental step is not an effective development methodology. If you just want a working site without having to learn anything, hire someone else to write it.

To address your suggestion of *"communicating orientation and goal"*, I don't think that you should. Meta-tags in general are not considered useful here, and remember that the point of SO is to build a library of useful answers. The next person with a similar question may have different goals to you, and that's perfectly fine.

Answer (score 15):

Frankly, I find this question kind of insulting towards the people who post answers on Stack Overflow, or at least showing an expectation that doesn't match with the reality of how the site is supposed to be used.

Please feel free to correct me, but I read it as *"I have no interest in learning about this subject, I expect you to fix my code"*. That's simply not how this site works.

Together, we're building (or at least trying to build) a collection of high-quality questions and answers that help many people. Answerers are **not** here to solve every single problem over and over again, but instead, we try to post reusable answers that apply to the broader subject, so that you, as a Googler who's doing their homework, can find these answers and apply them to their own variation of the same problem.

If you have no interest in learning about a specific subject, the alternative is not to post a question on Stack Overflow, but instead find a site where people (paid or for free) will do your work for you.

Comment: Indeed, future readers of the same post often are trying to become experts.